# Specifying shape of dataset when creating HDF5 file

Tags: rust, hdf5

I have a function with the following signature:

```
fn create_something( ... ) -> ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>> {
// Does stuff
}
```

I then call this function and I would like to save the data into a HDF5 file:

```
let data = create_something( ... );

    
let file = hdf5::File::create("./output/example.h5"); // open for writing
let group = file.create_group("example_group"); // create a group
let data_set = group.new_dataset::<f64>().create("example");
let write_res = data_set.write(data.view());
match write_res {
    Ok(_) => (),
    Err(error) => panic!("Error: {:?}", error)
}
```

Resulting in

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error: shape mismatch when writing: memory = [1950, 24191], destination = []', src/main.rs:203:27
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

So there seems to be a problem with the shape, which is reasonable since I haven't really specified the shape of the dataset... What I don't understand, is how I can specify this (I find the [documentation](https://docs.rs/hdf5/latest/hdf5/index.html) on this very confusing...) and how exactly one could append data to the data-set if we need to know its exact shape at creation...

Comment: Hi @Sito, it's been a long time since I've worked with hdf5 and I'm _very_ new to Rust... With that said, does the [`resize`](https://docs.rs/hdf5/latest/hdf5/dataset/struct.Dataset.html#method.resize) method on the `Dataset` get you there?

Comment: @vitale232 I don't think you can call the resize function on `data_set`, but I'm not sure if this is even the problem... I mean, according to the error message it also says I haven't really specified the `destination`, but I'm not really sure how to do that/why this is not done automatically when creating the dataset...

Answer (score 2):

The basic issue is that you need to tell the HDF5 library the shape of the in-file dataset.

HDF5 is extremely flexible, the cost of which is complexity. It's possible to convert data between a file and the in-memory representation in a whole host of ways, including reshaping, transposing, swapping byte order, converting types, and much more.

For example, you can read every other sample from a file, into a contiguous array in memory. The details of these two different representations is captured by a [*dataspace*](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/HDF5-1.8.7/UG/UG_frame12Dataspaces.html). These can be different for an in-file and in-memory dataset.

In your example, you've declared a dataset with a particular name and datatype (`f64`), but given the HDF5 library no other information about it. The library does *not* assume that, because you've provided a contiguous array of some size, that the datapsace *is* that size, again, because you can read/write between a dataspaces that are of different sizes.

In this case, all you need to add is the shape of the dataset.

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = vec![0.0, 1.0, 2.0];
    let file = hdf5::File::create("./example.h5").unwrap(); // open for writing
    let group = file.create_group("example_group").unwrap(); // create a group
    let data_set = group
        .new_dataset::<f64>()
        .shape([data.len()])
        .create("example")
        .unwrap();
    let write_res = data_set.write(&data);
    match write_res {
        Ok(_) => (),
        Err(error) => panic!("Error: {:?}", error),
    }
}
```

You can see the file is appropriately filled:

```sh
$ h5dump example.h5
HDF5 "example.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   GROUP "example_group" {
      DATASET "example" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F64LE
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 3 ) / ( 3 ) }
         DATA {
         (0): 0, 1, 2
         }
      }
   }
}
}
```